# Having problem when comparing two strings

Tags: java

I'm reading a CSV file using Java. Inside the file, each row is in this format:

```
operation, start, end.
```

I need to do a different operation for different input. But something weird happened when I'm trying to compare two string.

I used equals to compare two strings. And one of the operation is "add", but the first element I fetched from the document always give me the wrong answer. I know that's an "add" and I printed it out it looks like an "add", but when I'm using `operation.equals("add")`, it's `false`. For all rest of Strings it's correct except the first one. Is there anything special about the first row in CSV file?

Here is my code:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] data = line.split(",");
    String operation = data[0];
    int start = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
    int end = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);
    System.out.println(operation + " " + start + " " + end);
    System.out.println(operation.equals("add"));
```

For example, it printed out 
add 1 3
false
add 4 6
true
And I really don't know why. These two *add* looks exactly the same.

And here is what my csv file look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxr4B.png)

Comment: Maybe there are spaces around, use trim.

Comment: I just tried but it's not working.

Comment: try this operation.trim().equals("add")

Comment: Please also provide the lines of code where you read from the file AND where you "tokenize" the line. Maybe you need to trim some comma, not spaces.

Comment: As I can see, the csv does not have new-lines. Operations should start on a new line, not concatenated to the last "end".

Comment: I didn't really change the string "operation", I just printed it out. "add" is still "add".

Comment: It really prints `"add 1 3"`?! The csv has `"add,0,3"`.

Comment: Could you give HEX representation of the file? I would like to look at encoding header.

Comment: Please also print contents of `line` and `data`.

Comment: Problem solved! I saved it in the wrong csv file! The one I used before is CSV UTF-8(Comma delimited), and I just changed it to normal comma separated values file. I hardly used a CSV file so I didn't realize there two kinds of them before. Anyway, thank you for your comment oleg, it really gives me a lot of hint!

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) 4 reasons why two string that "look" like they are the same when you display / print them could turn out to be non-equal:

1. If you compare Strings using `==` rather than `equals(Object)`, then you will often get the wrong answer.  (This is not the problem here ... since you are using the `equals` method.  However, this is a [common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).)
2. Unexpected leading or trailing whitespace characters on one string.  These can be removed using `trim()`.
3. Other leading, trailing or embedded control characters or Unicode "funky" characters.  For example stray Unicode [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (byte order mark) characters.
4. [Homoglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph).  There are a number of examples where two or more distinct Unicode code points are rendered on the screen using the same or virtually the same glyphs.

Cases 3 and 4 can only be reliably detected by using traceprints or a debugger to examine the lengths and the `char` values in the two strings.

(Screen shots of the CSV file won't help us to diagnose this!  A cut-and-paste of the CSV file *might* help.)

Comment: Up-voted. Debugger and memory inspection should be done before asking question, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the double quotes from the first element and then check with equals method.

Try this:

```
String operation = operation.substring(1, to.length() - 1);
operation.equals("add")
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: There are no double quotes in it : (

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your line in image looks fine. I suppose in this case, that you could set wrong document encoding. E.g. when UTF, and you do not put it, then is has special header at the beginning. It could be a reason, why you read first word incorrectly.

Comment: line in the image is **NOT** csv because there are no new-lines. Sorry I cannot yet downvote.

Comment: I suppose this is editor feature (probably illegal new line or so).